# CS50 pset4 - filter (less comfortable), blur function

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote a code for the blur function of the filter pset. However, whenever I try to compile the code, I get an error. Can someone see where my mistake lies?

Code:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int red = 0;
            int green = 0;
            int blue = 0;

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1  <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1  <= 255 && i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  <= 255 && i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1  <= 255 && i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  <= 255 && i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = (red / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (green / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (blue / count);

        }

    }
    return;
}
```

Error message:

```
helpers.c:170:24: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:171:26: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:172:25: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:178:24: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:179:26: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:180:25: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:146:24: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:147:26: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:148:25: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:154:24: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:155:26: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:156:25: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
```

My input is:

```
./filter -b stadium.bmp outfile.bmp
```

If anyone needs more information on the pset, please feel free to head over to CS50's own page:

https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/less/

updated code:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int red = 0;
            int green = 0;
            int blue = 0;


            if (j - 1 >= 0 & j - 1  <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1  <= 255 && i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  <= 255 && i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i- 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i- 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1  <= 255 && i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i + 1] [j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i+ 1][j ].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i+ 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i+ 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  <= 255 && i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 <= 255)
            {
                red += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i+ 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i+ 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / count);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / count);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / count);

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

update 2:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];


    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float red = 0;
            float green = 0;
            float blue = 0;

            int count = 0;

            if (j >= 0 )
            {
                red += image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1  < width- 1)
            {
                red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  < width - 1)
            {
                red += image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1  < width - 1 && i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 < height - 1)
            {
                red += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 < height - 1)
            {
                red += image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  < width - 1 && i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 < height - 1)
            {
                red += image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i- 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i- 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && j - 1  < width - 1 && i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 < height - 1)
            {
                red += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i + 1] [j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 < height - 1)
            {
                red += image[i+ 1][j ].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i+ 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i+ 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  < width- 1 && i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 < height - 1)
            {
                red += image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i+ 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i+ 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }

            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / count);
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / count);
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / count);


        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

error message after running test code:

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "70 85 95\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "81 101 65\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "70 85 95\n", not "45 72 71\n"
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "49 57 71\n61 6..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "46 60 79\n85 8..."
```

Comment: You start the loop with `j=0`... `if (i + 1 >= 0 && i + 1 <= 255) {red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;` ==> `j-1 == -1` as mentioned in the error messages. Your range checks are not correct.

Comment: thanks. I fixed it. However, the outfile.bmp is not getting blurred. It is getting is blue-ish color grade. Do you see something wrong in the code that I have not seen so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are various errors in your code.

1. The invalid index values are caused by incorrect conditions for your pixel access:

   ```
       if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  <= 255 && i - 1 >= 0 && i - 1 <= 255)
       {
           red += image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
           green += image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
           blue += image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
           count++;
       }
   ```

   The condition will be true for `j==0` which will cause access to `image[i][-1]` as indicated in the error message.
2. You never reset `count`.
   Variable `count` is intented to track how many neighbouring pixels were included in calculating an average. This should be reset for each pixel instead of groving endlessly.
3. You use integers for calculation.
   The question asks you to apply proper rounding to the nearest color. This implies using floating point variables instead of integers as integer division always rounds down.
4. You should use all neighbouring pixels.
   This means you need to use offset -1,0,+1 within the row as well as withing the column. In other words you must use index values `[i-1][...]`, `[i][...]`and `[i+1][...]` as well as `[...][j-1]`, `[...][j]`and `[...][j+1]`. In total you should have 9 pixels taken into account for all non-edge pixels. Your current code uses `[i][j - 1]` way more often than any other pixel giving it a much higher weight than other pixels. Some neighbours are never used.
5. The conditions take a fixed magic number `255` for width and height of the bitmap. You should use variables `height` and `width` instead.
6. Conditions are too complex.
   In each conditional block you access a pixel that is off by 1 in any direction. If you use `j+1` you don't need to check if it is less than 0. Also if you use `i-1` there is no need to compare against upper bound. And if you don't use an offset (`[i]`) you do not need to check range of `i` at all, as the outer loops already take care about that.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            double red   = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            double green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            double blue  = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            int count = 1;

            if (j > 0)
            {
                red += image[i][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }
            ...
            if (i < height-1 && j > 0)
            {
                red += image[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green += image[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += image[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                count++;
            }
```

7. You already use blurred pixels during your calculation.
   If you update a pixel `image[i][j]` with a new value and in the next step you use it again via `image[i][j-1]` you will get false results. Use a copy of the image instead to store the resulting pixels.

Comment: I corrected my code as much as I could/understood from your code. The picture gets blurred, however the code fails the testing

Comment: Your conditions are still too complex. And you are off by 1 for some conditions. `if (j + 1 >= 0 && j + 1  < width - 1)` As I already mentions, `j>0`will always be true due to your loop. Then `j+1>0` is always true as well, of course. Then either compare `j+1` or `width-1` not both. You skip the last column of pixels. This condition should simply be `if (j + 1  < width)`

Comment: Are there any more details besides "fails the test"?

Comment: more details added. simplifying conditions did not solve the problem

Comment: You should still remove the useless parts and make it better readable. And also fix the missing edges. You don't have the test images, do you?

Answer (score 0):

```
RGBTRIPLE arr[height][width];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = image[i][j];
    }
}
float r, b, g;
float counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
        {
            for (int l = -1; l < 2; l++)
            {
                if (i + k >= 0 && j + l >= 0 && i + k <= height - 1 && j + l <= width - 1)
                {
                    r += arr[i + k][j + l].rgbtRed;
                    b += arr[i + k][j + l].rgbtBlue;
                    g += arr[i + k][j + l].rgbtGreen;
                    counter++;
                }

            }
        }
        r = r / counter;
        b = b / counter;
        g = g / counter;
        if (r > 255)
        {
            r = 255;
        }
        if (r < 0)
        {
            r = 0;
        }
        if (g > 255)
        {
            g = 255;
        }
        if (g < 0)
        {
            g = 0;
        }
        if (b > 255)
        {
            b = 255;
        }
        if (b < 0)
        {
            b = 0;
        }
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(r);
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(b);
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(g);
        counter = 0;
        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.